# How to set pandas value count to 0, if data frame is empty

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a dataframe and a plot

```
if data1.empty:
    pass
else:
    ax = data1['30'].value_counts(sort=True).plot(kind='bar',width=0.1, figsize=(10,8),
                                                color="red", fontsize=13,position=1)
```

At times `data1` becomes empty. Now I am using a `pass`. But I would like to change pass with some code that will assign the count as zero and will plot as 0 in graph.

Comment: Given the information that you provided, your question cannot be answered. I suggest that you explain what exactly you expect as the output when a dataframe is empty. I have never seen a plot of an empty dataframe, surprise me.

Comment: Do you need `pd.Series([0]).plot(kind='bar',width=0.1, figsize=(10,8), color="red", fontsize=13,position=1)` instead `pass`?

Comment: @jezrael this will consider value 0 as count? if yes this is what I require

Comment: @qwww - yes, can you test it with real code, if it working for you?

Comment: please post it as an answer..it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `Series` with value `0` and plot it instead `pass`:

```
pd.Series([0]).plot(kind='bar',width=0.1, figsize=(10,8), color="red", fontsize=13,position=1)
```

Comment: How to make only count as 0 and not the label value? because I am getting label value itself as 0

Comment: @qwww - Use `pd.Series([0], index=['val']).plot(kind='bar')`